# Importing Contacts from Access

Tags: data-import, csv

I understand I need to convert a table into a csv file, but the contact table in question has both an individual and their spouse in the same record.  Now I can build a query that would only show me the individual's information, but once I import that information into civicrm how would I then import a list of spouses and get them to setup relationships, or will I just have to manually enter those in after importing the primary contact information?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit complicated. You will need to do at least 2 different imports, with external IDs. The CSVs for imports would look at this

1st import

```
first_name, last_name, extID
Jane, Doe, 1
```

2nd import

```
first_name, last_name, extID, Spouse-extID
John, Doe, 2, 1
```

Take a look at [CiviCRM 5.29.0 - import relationships](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38342/civicrm-5-29-0-import-relationships?rq=1)